# Magento 2 : Add helper condition on layout file

Tags: magento2

I need to add helper condition to show the layout block. So this layout block only show if condition match in helper function. Is any way to add any condition in layout to directly check the helper for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From your question i can understand based on the condition you want to show that block or not for example , so this is how you can do ,you have to set the ifconfig ,please do let know if it helps or not. please refer the below image[image]

Comment: Thanks @bharath but i want to check the condition through helper function not through the config setting. Is any option to add helper function in layout?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 there are several ways of showing and hiding blocks conditionally.

> 1. If its visibility depends on a configuration settings value, use the ifconfig expression in your layout file

```
<referenceContainer name='form.buttons'>
    <block
        class='Dfe\Google\Block\Backend\Template'
        name='Dfe_Google_Backend_Buttons'
        template='buttons.phtml'
        after='adminhtml_auth_login_buttons'
        ifconfig='dfe_google/login/enable'
    />
</referenceContainer>
```

> 2. In case of a more complex visibility condition, show and hide a block by overriding
>    the\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::toHtml() method.

The block won’t be shown If you return the empty string from the method.

```
<?php
namespace Dfe\Facebook\Block;
class Login extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link {
    /**
    * @override
    * @see \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link::toHtml()
    * @return string
    */
    public function toHtml() {return !rm_customer_logged_in() ? parent::toHtml() : '';}
} ?>
```

> 3. ACL condition

```
<block class="Magento\AdminNotification\Block\Window"
name="notification_window"
as="notification_window"
aclResource="Magento_AdminNotification::show_toolbar"
template="Magento_AdminNotification::notification/window.phtml"/>
```

> 4. Add Custom conditions like below

```
<referenceContainer name="header">
    <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\CustomBlock" name="customblock.content">
        <visibilityCondition name="customblock" className="Namespace\Module\Block\CustomBlock\Condition" />
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

You can use this for uiComponent also. like below

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <uiComponent name="release_notification"> <!-- your uiComponent name -->
        <visibilityCondition name="customblock" className="Namespace\Module\Block\CustomBlock\Condition" />
    </uiComponent>
</referenceContainer>
```

In above block, we declar new visibility condition on our CustomBlock block - we provide it’s name and classname - which will be responsible for decision logic - whether block should be rendered or not. Let’s create new class Namespace\Module\Block\CustomBlock\Condition:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Block\CustomBlock;

class Condition implements \Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Condition\VisibilityConditionInterface
{
    
    private static $conditionName = 'custom_block';

    public function isVisible(array $arguments)
    {
        return (bool)$value;  
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::$conditionName;
    }
}

?>
```

As per your requirement you can use 2nd or 4th solution.
You can check helper function in block and if helper function return false value then you can return empty string from the block so it will not display.